# Image that scales so you always can see the whole image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my site where I am testing my project: http://www.rojje.com/. If you want to see what I am trying to achieve then use the username: "test" with password: "password" or create a new user.
The first page after login is a page with a image that I want scalable.

Edit: I found the solution but it only works when I use `top:0` and if I remove `top:0` it will remove a part in the bottom of the image.

If you remove `top:0` you will se whats behind the pic:                    http://jsfiddle.net/g9hh6qvb/

Comment: You can use bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Comment: You can make it a background-image for a div with 100% width/height. Then add `background-size: cover`

Comment: use bootstrap (use the grid system > .img-responsive class), that's all you need in order to make responsive content which will work on mobile devices as well. Are you planning to make this for desktop devices only or for mobile devices aswell?

Comment: Thanks I will check out the grid system. The project is for booth mobile and desktop

Answer (score 1):

You can define a background-image in css and set the background-size to 'cover' or 'contain', see for example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Mind you that the example you give is made using Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **background-attachment:scroll**, also set the background size with **background-size: cover** when setting up your style. According to the documentation description it attaches the background to the element itself, so re-sizing the element should re-size the background image also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS background-size attribute 'Cover' as mentioned, if your image is set as the background of a div.  If you are using an `<img/>` tag in your HTML, you can also (see both examples below):

CSS:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

.section{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:purple;
}

.section:first-child img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    min-height:100%;
    display:block;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width:100%;  
}

div:nth-child(3){
      background: url("http://th02.deviantart.net/fs42/PRE/f/2009/133/a/0/Rainy_Landscape_STOCK_by_wyldraven.jpg")no-repeat fixed center;
      background-size:cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
   <img src="http://th02.deviantart.net/fs42/PRE/f/2009/133/a/0/Rainy_Landscape_STOCK_by_wyldraven.jpg">
</div>
<div class="section">
</div>
<div class="section">
</div>
```

Example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dclappert/pen/GJpGYE?editors=110)

Comment: Thanks but this is not really what I want  because I can change the window  size and not seeing  the whole image.